# BufferedReader mock. readLine() need to be called only once

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Can anybody give an advice how to make `when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(line);`
call only once ?
Because I have a while loop through all lines, and I want to test only single line.

Comment: You are asking how to make it return line once and null after that right? Can you also please post the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

thenReturn takes varargs if you want to change the return values for subsequent calls.

```
when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(line, null);
```

This will cause it to return line the first time and null every time after.

EDIT:
Note that you can also do the following to get the same results:

```
when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(line).thenReturn(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is better to use a real but simple `BufferedReader` instead of a stub for your test.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new StringReader(line)
);
```

The contract of a BufferedReader is complex. Hence your test with a stub may fail if you change internals of your code (e.g. read single characters instead of lines) although the code is still correct.